# OFX APPID Usage

Tags: ofx, quicken

The Quicken OFX AppID and AppVer are available in multiple websites and there are lot of other personal accounting softwares (GNUCash) that I can use Quicken OFX data to connect to banking server. Is it legal to use Quicken OFX AppId and AppVer in other software products?

Answer (score 0):

While I am no legal expert, you seem to be conflating terminology-

- *.ofx stands for **Open** Financial Exchange documents, which can be used by anyone.
- *.qfx stands for **Quicken** Financial (proprietary) documents which are bound by license and usually associated with fees paid through your bank.

The two file formats are very similar, with the addition of some proprietary tags and session data which exist only in the Quicken file types.  If the tags you are referring to don't exist in the open OFX format definition (found [here](http://www.ofx.net/OFXPrefixesPage/OFXPrefixesPage.aspx)) then you're out of luck.